# The difference of `InputStream`  `DataInputStream` and `BufferedInputStream`  in java? 

Tags: java

The difference of `InputStream`  `DataInputStream` and `BufferedInputStream`  in java?

Comment: You mean what's the difference ?

Comment: Read the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If the question is : "what the difference between those classes", here is a summary, but read the javadoc for more info :

An inputStream is the base class to read bytes from a stream (network or file). It provides the ability to read bytes from the stream and detect the end of the stream.

DataInputStream is a kind of InputStream to read data directly as primitive data types.

BufferedInputStream is a kind of inputStream that reads data from a stream and uses a buffer to optimize speed access to data. data is basicaly read ahead of time and this reduces disk or network access.

Comment: DataInputStream doesn't do Objects.  I think you are confusing it with ObjectInputStream.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are asking difference so i am giving some details

`Input Stream means`:this abstract class is the superclass of all classes representing an input stream of bytes.Applications that need to define a subclass of InputStream must always provide a method that returns the next byte of input.

`DataInputStream`:A data input stream lets an application read primitive Java data types from an underlying input stream in a machine-independent way. An application uses a data output stream to write data that can later be read by a data input stream.

For More use this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html

`BufferedInputStream`:A BufferedInputStream adds functionality to another input stream-namely, the ability to buffer the input and to support the mark and reset methods. When the BufferedInputStream is created, an internal buffer array is created. As bytes from the stream are read or skipped, the internal buffer is refilled as necessary from the contained input stream, many bytes at a time.

Comment: you copied and pasted the opening paragraphs from the docs, could have just given the link.

Comment: I have given the link also. But some times link will expire or link will give a 404 error.