# Java, why is BufferedInputStream used in this code?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the use of BufferedInputStream in this code.
We are writing here from inputStream to outputStream, so what is the point of BufferedInputStream? What does it buffer, if the process of reading and writing happens byte by byte.

```
  public static void executor(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws Exception {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            int data = bis.read();
            outputStream.write(data);
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805192/the-difference-of-inputstream-datainputstream-and-bufferedinputstream-in

Comment: TL;DR by reading in larger blocks of data it is more efficient ... the underlying element is interacted with in chunks of 8192 (default size) bytes, even if the copy is going a byte at a time (as it is in the question).

Comment: Because it is reading one byte at a time, which would be very inefficient without the buffer. NB This is a typical misuse of `available()`: do not copy. It should read until end of stream (`read()` returns -1) or some defined length or content is attained. As it copies a byte at a time it should also use a `BufferedOutputStream`, and flush it when done. Better still, it should use `read(byte[])` and `write(byte[],int,int)` with a reasonably large buffer, say 8k. Calling the method `executor()` when it is just a copy operation is also poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

The BufferedInputStream is used for performance optimization. A BufferedInputStream wraps around another [InputStream](https://coderfoobar.com/what-is-a-java-inputstream/) like FileInputStream and buffers data. What BufferedInputStream does is that it collects multiple chunks of bytes so that you can read larger chunks of data at once for performance.